# Can Anabin analyze a degree if you don't have it yet?

Tags: germany

I know that in order to have your degree recognized in Germany, it needs to show up in Anabin (which is handled by the ZAB). However, I noticed that if your degree from your university IS there, you don't need to request a statement of comparability for it.

This makes me wonder, is the recognition process for the degree not personal? Could I just request the recognition if my uni is listed as H+ by just providing them the name of the degree, the syllabus and all of that relevant info?

In short: does that "statement of comparability" process requires you to provide a document that belongs to YOU specifically or they only need general info about the degree?

The recognition process takes like 3 months... I'd really like to request for it earlier if possible.